# SP13: Outlook Calendar Events to SP Calendar

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, calendar, outlook

I know there's a way of doing this in SP10.  I have created a calendar in sharepoint to replace a outlook calendar.  In stead having to enter all the entries manually into the sharepoint calendar.

Is there a way to transfer the outlook events into the sharepoint calendar?  In SP10 you do this by exporting the outlook calendar into a Excel file.  Is this the same way it's done in SP13?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, Once you create a sharepoint cal, click "connect to outlook" and click yes to the pop up box. The calendar will appear in Outlook and when an event is added, it will appear automatically in sharepoint! Let me know if this helps.